# Cycle through chrome tabs until a specific one is found - Autohotkey

Tags: windows, automation, autohotkey

Good day!
This script should go to Chrome and cycle through the tabs until it finds a specified one (in this case YouTube), then send a command and return to my initial window.
The problem is that it just switches to chrome and doesn't cycle through the tabs, even sometimes it bugs.
Thank you :)

```
settitlematchmode, 2
^f1::
If Not WinExist("ahk_exe chrome.exe")
 {
 Return
 }
WinGetTitle, Title, A
WinActivate, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
 Loop{
  Send, ^{Tab}
  Sleep, 50
  WinGetTitle, CurrentWindowTitle, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
  If CurrentWindowTitle contains YouTube
   {
   send {Space}
   ;~ Send {Alt down}   ;back to old window
   ;~ Send {tab}
   WinActivate, %Title%
   Sleep 300
   If not WinActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe
    {
    Send {Alt up}
    break
    Return
    }
   break
   Return
   }
  }
Return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do use **WinWaitActive** after WinActivate:

```
settitlematchmode, 2

^f1::
If Not WinExist("ahk_exe chrome.exe")
    Return
WinGetTitle, Title, A
WinActivate, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
WinWaitActive, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
Loop
{
    Send, ^{Tab}
    WinGetTitle, CurrentWindowTitle, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
    If CurrentWindowTitle contains YouTube
    {
       send {Space}
       break
    }   
}
WinActivate, %Title%
WinWaitActive, %Title% 
Return
```